# How to invoke and call an attribute for a static function?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to understand the limitations on attributes in C#. I'd like to apply an attribute to a static function like so:

```
1 public class Simple : System.Attribute
2 {
3    public Simple() { System.Console.WriteLine("Simple ct"); }
4 }
...
5 [Simple]
6 public static void DummyFn()
7 {
8    System.Console.WriteLine("Dummy fn!");
9 }
...
10 DummyFn();
```

So, here's what I want to happen:

- Line 10 invokes DummyFn.
- When DummyFn is invoked, the Simple() constructor gets called, which emits the line "Simple ct".
- After which DummyFn() gets called, which emits the line "Dummy fn!"

As far as I can tell, this doesn't work. If, however, I make DummyFn() non-static, it does work. Can someone help me understand this behavior?

Comment: Are you sure `Simple` constructor is called? It shouldn't be in the code provided. Attributes are constructed only where examined via type's metadata. Do you work in context of any framework?

Comment: Nope, Simple() is NOT called. That's the point. I would like to know if it's possible to amend the example to ensure that Simple() is called :)

Comment: You've stated that it's called when not static. I was asking about that part.

Comment: @Stephen: I think A's point is that `Simple()` constructor shouldn't be called even if `DummyFn()` is an instance method (non-static) though you seem to indicate it does...

Comment: I'm quite sure Simple() gets called if DummyFn() is non-static. I tried both versions: the non-static form definitely calls Simple(); the static forms does not.

Comment: Plain .NET console application? No frameworks, AOP libraries etc.?

Comment: @StephenGross: if the _only_ reference to `Simple` is the attribute declaration `[Simple]` then the attribute will _not_ have been called (unless you use a special library, as A suggests). It's not the way attributes are supposed to work. They decorate. They don't execute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want your attribute to be constructed, you have to query the metadata as so

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        InvokeTest(new Action(Program.Crap));

        var p = new Program();

        Console.WriteLine(InvokeTest(new Func<int, int>(p.Pipi), 3));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static object InvokeTest(Delegate d, params object[] args)
    {
        d.Method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(CocoAttribute), false);

        return d.DynamicInvoke(args);
    }

    [Coco]
    static void Crap()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Caca");
    }

    [Coco]
    int Pipi(int a)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Pipi: " + a);

        return a * 2;
    }
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = true)]
sealed class CocoAttribute : Attribute
{
    // This is a positional argument
    public CocoAttribute()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Coco");
    }
}
```

This program will show
Coco
Caca
Coco
Pipi: 3
6

--- With your permission Francis, I edited your answer.

And this won't work

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        new Program().DummyFn();
    }

    public class Simple : System.Attribute
    {
        public Simple()
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Simple ct");
        }
    }

    [Simple]
    public void DummyFn()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Dummy fn!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Whoa... Ok, well, I believe you that your example would work. Man, that is intense. I was hoping there might be a simpler way...